Two functors produce the same objects
I am doing Algebraic Topology with a bare minimum knowledge in Category Theory. I am writing the proof of Universal Coefficient Theorem, and it uses a categorical lemma as follows
Let $C, D$ be categories and $F, G$ be functors from $C$ to $D$. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism in $C$. If $FX = GX$ and $FY=GY$, then $Ff = Gf$
The statement is true if $C, D$ is the category of abelian groups and $F,G$ are homomorphisms, in that case, the commutativity of the square $(FX, FY, GY, GX)$ can be realized from a bunch of commutative squares.

I wonder if there is anyway to generalize it?

The statement fails even if $D=C$. Otherwise, specializing to the case of monoids (categories with a single object), the statement would then say that any two monoid homomorphisms between the same two monoids are equal, which of course, is absurd.

You allude to a commutative square, but where is that coming from?

@khanh It's not true of $\mathrm{Ab}$ either. There's a functor taking $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself and everything else to the trivial group which takes an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself (and all other morphisms to the unique morphism into the trivial group), but there's also a functor doing the same on objects which on morphisms takes every endomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$ to the identity.

The squares you draw do not need to commute, and those with arrows from $X$ (resp. $Y$) to $GX$ or $FX$ (resp. $GY$ or $FY$) need not even exist. It seems like you assume the existence of natural transformations $\mathrm{id}_C\to F$ and $F\to G$, such that the latter is objectwise an identity morphism (and hence a natural isomorphism of functors). The latter would indeed give you $G=F$ as functors, but assuming a natural transformation that is objectwise the identity is an extremely strong assumption on your functors.

@DaniëlApol thanks, I missed it here.

It doesn't use this lemma at all (because it is not a lemma). But maybe ! you are noting a certain sloppiness; maybe the author said "obviously these morphisms are the same" or maybe they didn't say anything at all, and just implicitly said these two arrows are the same. This is extremely common and you should watch out for it, if you care about details...

But regardless it would be helpful to show the specific context where you think this lemma is being applied, so we can help you understand the proof

@FShrike the natural transformation from $H_n(-) \otimes N$ to $H_n(- \otimes N)$

That's a bit vague :) sorry. Maybe you could edit your post with an extract from the proof and we can help there. To be clear: I know proofs of this theorem, so the issue is that I don't really know what your confusion is

@FShrike you want to extend the short exact sequence $0 \to B_n \to Z_n \to H_n(C_\bullet) \to 0$ by the left derived functor of $(- \otimes N)$. The result sequence will be $... \to Tor_1(Z_n, N) \to Tor_1(H_n(C_\bullet), N) \to B_n \otimes N \to Z_n \otimes N \to H_n(C_\bullet) \otimes N \to 0$. Then, the map $B_n \otimes N \to Z_n \otimes N$ has cokernel being $H_n(C_\bullet) \otimes N$ and kernel being $Tor_1(H_n(C_\bullet), N)$ because $Z_n$ is projective.
Commutative diagram of 4 objects: $(B_n \otimes N, Z_n \otimes N, H_n(B_\bullet \otimes N), H_n(Z_\bullet \otimes N))$

@FShrike replace $B_n$ by $H_n(B_\bullet)$, $Z_n$ by $H_n(Z_\bullet)$ then what we want is a natural transformation from $H_n(-) \otimes N$ to $H_n(- \otimes N)$ which can be proved by construction. It seems that these two functors are natural to the identity as well.

I don’t think you understand what I’m saying. I know the proof! I just don’t know what is confusing you.

@FShrike also made a more general question regarding this here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4907509/700122

You are still misunderstanding me. I know the proof!! I’m trying to get you to elaborate on what you are confused by. But I think I can guess the issue now. I’ve left a comment under your other post

@FShrike As the issue was resolved 20 hours ago, the proof is done. I don't think these comments are meaningful.
